# How do I construct the multiplication of a quotient group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is:
If $G$ is the group of all nonzero real numbers under multiplication and $N$ 
is the subgroup of all positive real numbers, write out $G/N$ by exhibiting 
the cosets of $N$ in $G$, and construct the multiplication in $G/N$.

Okay I am confused about what is sufficient answer in writing out the quotient group by exhibiting the cosets of $N$ in $G$: for example I wrote $G/N = \{[a] | a \in G\} = \{Na | a \in G\}$. Is that enough?

And for the construction of multiplication do I use $ [a] = [a']$ and $[b] = [b'] $to end up with $NaNb = Nab$?

Final question: we learned that you need a normal subgroup to prove this for for the given problem should I strt out by proving $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This answer would not satisfy me, because you haven’t shown that you’ve seen what the cosets are. What is the trivial coset? How many nontrivial cosets can you find? Finally, your groups are commutative, so all subgroups are normal; this is not a problem here.

Comment: I know the trivial coset but the other cosets would just be mulitples of the positive real numbers? and wouldn't there be an infinite number?

Comment: You've written down the definition of a coset. The question is not asking you to repeat definitions, but to work out specifically in this case what the cosets are. You're trying to work out an example.

Comment: I would not be satisfied with your response till I saw an explicit description of the trivial coset, in the form $\{x\in\mathbb R\colon\cdots\}$, and the similarly-worded description of any other coset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You learned this a long time ago:

"Positive times positive is positive",

"Positive times negative is negative",

"Negative times positive is negative",

"Negative times negative is positive".

The quotient group is of order 2. $N$ is automatically normal because $G$ is abelian. By definition:

$aN = bN$ if $a^{-1}b \in N$, which happens if and only if either both $a,b \in N$ or $a,b \not\in N$.

The two cosets are, explicitly: $N$ and $-N$, and these can be regarded as $[1]$ and $[-1]$.

---

This uses properties of the real numbers, which you are expected to know. The relevant property, here, is:

$\forall x \in \Bbb R-\{0\},\ x^2 > 0$ (that is: $x^2 \in N$).

This shows that for ANY coset $xN$, we have $(xN)(xN) = x^2N = N$.

So our cosets can only have order 1 ($N$ itself), or order 2.

Now if $y \not\in N$ (that is $y < 0$, see below) we have:

$(-1)^{-1}y = (\frac{1}{-1})y = (-1)y = -y \in N$, so that $yN = (-1)N$ which shows that the only OTHER coset is: $(-1)N = -N\ $ (this uses the trichotomy rule of the order on the real numbers).